# simple spring java configuration error

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

I´m following the tutorialspoint for Spring, and I´m trying the example for Java based configuration. I had the same code as the tutorial, but I don´t understand why is marking a NullPointerException.

This is my model

```
package com.tutorialspoint3.javaConfig;

public class HelloWorld {

    private String message;

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void getMessage() {

        System.out.println("Your message: " + message);
    }

}
```

My configuration class

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

//Configuration class

@Configuration
public class HelloWorldConfig {

    @Bean
    public HelloWorld helloWorld(){

        return new HelloWorld();
    }

}
```

and my main

```
package com.tutorialspoint3.javaConfig;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class MainApp3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext ctx =
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(HelloWorldConfig.class);

        HelloWorld helloWorld = ctx.getBean(HelloWorld.class);
        helloWorld.setMessage("Hello World!");
        helloWorld.getMessage();
    }

}
```

And this is the stack error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper$TypeProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:239)
    at org.springframework.core.$Proxy0.hashCode(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:273)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.hashCode(ResolvableType.java:811)
    at org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.getHash(ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.java:214)
    at org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.getReference(ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.java:246)
    at org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.get(ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.java:226)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forType(ResolvableType.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forType(ResolvableType.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forTypes(ResolvableType.java:856)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.getInterfaces(ResolvableType.java:403)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.as(ResolvableType.java:365)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.getRequiredTypeInfo(GenericConversionService.java:286)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.addConverterFactory(GenericConversionService.java:118)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.addScalarConverters(DefaultConversionService.java:86)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.addDefaultConverters(DefaultConversionService.java:67)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.<init>(DefaultConversionService.java:54)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.<init>(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:41)
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.<init>(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:41)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.<init>(AbstractEnvironment.java:112)
    at org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment.<init>(StandardEnvironment.java:54)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.getOrCreateEnvironment(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:177)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.<init>(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:66)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:61)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:82)
    at com.tutorialspoint3.javaConfig.MainApp3.main(MainApp3.java:11)
```

What I am missing? I´m running under jre 1.7 and the Spring version is 4.1.4. If I run under jdk 1.8 I got the error

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getMethod(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;

Comment: I would say you are mixing versions of spring jars.

Comment: as jars I have spring-core-2.0.4 and org.springframework.core , with which versions should I be working with? and do I really need those jars?

Comment: According to yourself 4.1.4... I strongly suggest to use something like maven or gradle to manage your dependencies instead of trying to figure out what to use together.

Comment: I´m using maven, now I see, for some reasons I added those jar files, but I removed them and now is working. Thank you for pointing to that direction

Comment: Everytime check compatibility of spring verssions and jdk as well as maintain same version for all spring jar

Comment: @NavnathAdsul thank you for your suggestion.